# C: Best Practise passing information from function to calling routine

Tags: c

Which would be the preferred way of passing information back, created in a function?

A)

```
create_b_from_a(... a, struct b *my_b) { ... }

int main() {
  struct b my_b;
  ... define and create a ...
  create_b_from_a(a, &my_b);
  ... work on b ...
}
```

B)

```
struct st *create_b_from_a(... a)
{
  struct st *my_b = malloc(sizeof *my_b);
  ...
}

int main()
{
  struct b *my_b = create_b_from_a(a);
  ... work on b ...
  free(b);
}
```

I think I remember something like 'avoid malloc when possible' but on the other hand B looks more modern to me. Maybe there are pros/cons to one of the approaches that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget that structs are values, so you are not restricted to those two. You can also do:

```
struct b create_b_from_a(struct a an_a)
{
  struct b new_b;

  new_b.field = value; /* and so on ... */

  return new_b;
}
```

This can also lead to cleaner code, since it's more straight-forward, not spending so much code on (micro) management.

And of course, if the compiler decides that on the target architecture actually passing a structure on the stack is horribly in-efficient, there are optimizations that target this pattern.

Comment: with the caveat that `struct b` should be of “reasonable size,” which generally means somewhere on the order of 4 × max of ( `sizeof(int)` `sizeof(void*)` ) or so, but this will vary a lot by architecture

Comment: doing it this way is good because the function can be referentially transparent. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_(computer_science)

Comment: @BRPocock: "reasonable size" is as big as you have time to copy memory that much memory. Since you had time to fill in all the fields, chances are good you have time to copy them. Optimize later.

Comment: "Reasonable size" = "small enough to not blow your stack" … which varies a lot from one system to another; defaults can vary from 4K (embedded Linux), 16K (HP/UX), up to 8M (MacOS) — figures from memory, may be inaccurate, but the point being: even dumping 1K onto the stack might be way too much for a small system. Very much a "Your Mileage Will Vary" kind of thing.

Comment: I was not aware that I can do it like this, agree that it is better than my two versions. (My struct is only of the size of 4-5 ints)

Comment: @SteveJessop and yes, 4 int/word/pointers is totally arbitrary upper limit, I believe that I picked that up from something about common systems and register sizes and copying to/from stack once-upon-a-time, but honestly, at this point I've just been so used to that limit that I don't really recall "why" it was a reasonable cap when I learnt it :-( That may very well be totally out-of-date for typical desktop & server systems

Comment: @BRPocock: Well, certainly a moderate number of objects of that size isn't going to blow the stack on *any* system, so maybe it's a conservative rule of thumb on that basis. But I think 4 words is the biggest that can be passed in registers on ARM. How many registers does x86 used for function parameters/return, it might be that too. That's a much tighter limit than you normally need to worry about going on the stack. Unless you're programming PIC or something, but I don't really expect my code to end up on PIC without someone reviewing it...

Comment: Interesting: `%eax Integral and pointer return values appear in %eax. A function that returns a struct or union value places the address of the result in %eax.` (Intel Sys V ABI, §3-11=p.37)

Answer (score 0):

Either way is acceptable, and I have in fact used both in my own time. I'm sure some people will have far more substantiated opinions with various rationales, but as far as IMO both have a time and a place, and it partially depends on the surrounding code, etc. If `b` will generally be local, then the first form might make more sense, since you don't really need dynamic memory anyway.